# Making a cell uneditable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview that is editable via an edit button:

[image]

After pressing edit:

[image]

I dont want the first column, "Activity Date' to be editable when the user presses 'edit'.

How do I prevent this control from changing into a textbox?

Edit here is the gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="viewHoursGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataKeyNames="PK_DailyTaskHours"
              BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
              CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" Width="94%" OnRowDeleting="viewHoursGridView_OnRowDeleting" OnRowEditing="viewHoursGridView_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="viewHoursGridView_RowUpdating"
              OnRowDataBound="viewHoursGridView_OnRowDataBound" CssClass="centerGridView">
    <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDate" HeaderText="Activity Date" SortExpression="ActivityDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Hours" HeaderText="Hours" SortExpression="Hours" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateDate" HeaderText="Created Date" SortExpression="CreateDate" Visible="false" />
       <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
       <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#7fc041" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ReadOnly` property.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.readonly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> BoundField.ReadOnly Property
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether
>   the value of the field can be modified in edit mode.

To use it in the Code-Behind:

```
((BoundField)viewHoursGridView.Columns[0]).ReadOnly = true;
```

Or in the ASPX code:

```
<asp:BoundField ReadOnly="True" DataField="ActivityDate" HeaderText="Activity Date" SortExpression="ActivityDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a template field as well...

```
<asp:TemplateField runat="server" ID="" HeaderText="Activity Date" 
                   SortExpression="ActivityDate">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" 
                   Text='<%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActivityDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ActivityDate") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you have access to the Telerik suite, you could use Telerik's RadmaskedTextBox over the textbox field to force user input.